# How can I upload a picture using Codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter

I want to know how I can upload an image and save its name in a database when using Codeigniter.
I am using a simple form tag for this, like:

```
<form action="./myaccount/index/" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <div>
        <label for="pic">picture</label>
         <input type="file" id="pic" name="pic" />
     </div>   
    <input id="register-btn" name="register" type="submit" value="ok" class="input-text custom-btn">
</form>
```

Here's my controller:

```
public function index() {

    $user = new User($_SESSION['user_id']);

    if($this->input->post()){

         $user->pic = $this->input->post('pic');

          if($this->input->post('password') == $this->input->post('confirm')){

               $user->password=md5(sha1(sha1($this->input->post('password'))));
               $user->save();
               $this->data['success'] = "done";

          }else{

               $this->errors[] = "error";
          }
      }

      $this->data['user'] = $user;
      $this->data['errors'] = $this->errors;
      $this->template->set_layout('myaccount');
      $this->template->build('profile',$this->data);
    }
```

I checked the manual but I can't understand what they are doing.
Im' trying to make a controler function for this that will insert all the values in the database and also upload the image file.

Comment: Please check File uploading class of CI will help you to upload pics http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/file_uploading.html

Comment: @umefarooq i try but i cannot solve my problem can you edit in my code

Comment: check out this simple tutorial http://codesamplez.com/development/codeigniter-file-upload it will tell  you how to upload file, one more thing if your file input field name not userfile then you have to give that name to do_upload like $this->upload->do_upload('pic')